# Python Class call Parent during Definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a pair of Python classes set up as such, with the inheritance of the `Foo` class by the `Bar` class.

Is there a way (what is the best way?) to call `desiredFunction`(where comment is) from the `Foo` class in the definition of the `Bar` class?

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def desiredFunction(cls,value):
        cls.classVariable+=value

class Bar(Foo):
    classVariable=1
    #desiredFunction right here in definition, called by Bar
```

Comment: The body of the class' definition will be executed only once, so you can move the call to `desiredFunction` outside.

Comment: Ah, so Bar.desiredFunction(value) outside? Not as pretty, but I guess that works.

Comment: There is no `Bar` class at the time you're trying to call the method. Why are you trying to call it at that point?

Comment: @ilcj: Why not `x.desiredFunction(value)`?

Comment: x is an instance, and I'm not really sure why I put it in the code anyway, since I'm making both Foo and Bar static classes lol

Comment: If you don't want to instantiate objects from them or not even from other classes that also derive from them, why don't you just group what you want in a module, then import and use the module, instead of using a `class`?